# Trigonometric Derivative

Tags: calculus

I have the derivative:

$$\frac{\sin(5-\theta)}{\theta^2}$$

When I go to solve it I am using the quotient rule; However when I went to check it on wolframalpha it states that I should be using the product rule.

Would anyone mind explaining to me why use of the product rule here is correct as it looks like a prime use of the quotient rule to me.

Comment: You can write $1/\theta^2 = \theta^{-2}$ and use the product rule.

Comment: Quotient rule is a direct result of product rule and chain rule that just makes it easier to derive fractions.  There's not much of a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient rule is usually derived from the product rule.

To prove the general formula, you can just rewrite $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to $f(x)(g(x))^{-1}$, and then apply the product rule. What you will find is that the end-result will be the quotient rule. Assuming $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the product rule if you set it equal to:

$sin(5-\theta)\theta^{-2}$

It doesn't really matter.